# best jprofiler offline snapshots size, framing and combination availability in UI

Tags: jboss, iot, jprofiler

I'm starting a small profiling project for the enterprise I work on.

We want to see where are the points of improvement of the system.

From the 2 options handled (profile with test or with QA environment) we decided the second.

The point now is, if we use the agent with and offline and save to an S3 bucket with the jpcontroller:

- how fast can and snapshot grow ? and how big if we continuously profile with all the opts activated?
- if we periodically save snapshots (let's say once a day) can we join / combine then to gather a week of data?

Thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to say this in general because the size of the snapshot depends on what your application is doing, what kind of data you are recording and how your profiling settings are configured. The snapshots could be very small or very large depending on all of these factors.

Comment: Danke schon Ingo, Weisst du darüber die Snapshot merging ??

Comment: On Stackoverflow you can only use English :-) I'm not sure what you mean by "snapshot merging"